# Lighthouse scores - is the new maximum 55?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying hard to improve my next.js website (thinkimmo.com). My current Lighthouse score is 44 - with some improvements left.
Still -> when I test the website vercel.com (which are the creators of next.js) I get a score of 55. So is 55 the new 100? How to get to 100? It seems quite impossible with next.js at the moment.

Comment: What makes you think it's impossible? It is definitely achievable. Are you stuck on any specific issue?

Comment: I'm using as said next.js and besides smaller things there is not much more that I can do (you can check it with LH). I checked Twitch, TikTok, Netflix - all of them are below 60. How the hell should I go to 100 then?